# How to make a data-block reference which count as an user?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I write a blender add-on for my one use (You can find a work in progress code version here: https://github.com/CaptainDesAstres/Frames-Animated-By-Curve ). In this script, I use a custom property which is a list of movie clips (see code here: https://github.com/CaptainDesAstres/Frames-Animated-By-Curve/blob/master/multi_track/TracksList.py ): I have a string property in which user can specify a movieclip name (or a path to load it). When this property is updated, a method add a «Track» object (which contain the name of the movie clip) to the list, so my add-on can manage every movieclip listed this way.

My problem is that: when I add a movie clip to the list, MovieClip.users doesn't increment. So, if the movie clip have no other user, it may be erase when saving file! I figured that I just have to increment manually MovieClip.users while adding it to the list and decrement while removing it from the list but I get an error : «AttributeError: bpy_struct: attribute "users" from "MovieClip" is read-only». I know I also can set MovieClip.use_fake_user to True but that doesn't seem clean to me. So how can I add a user reference to the movie clip?

Comment: Have you found an answer so far?